# Cordova create project

Tags: windows, cordova

I've got Apache Cordova (latest version as of today) installed on a Windows7 machine and am attempting to create a new project. I'm inside a firewall, so have set proxies (npm config set proxy ..., npm config set https-proxy ... ) to access internet.

using the following command:

cordova create testApp1

I get the following error output:

Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloCordova" and id "io.cordova.hellocordova" at location `"C:\Users\sr7\Documents\Cordova\testApp1"`
Downloading cordova library for www...

```
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error
    at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\sr7\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:168:17)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:199:16)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:315:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:529:20)
```

This would appear to be a proxy issue, however if I do this at home (i.e. no proxy), it still fails although the error is different, i.e.

Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloCordova" and id "io.cordova.hellocordova" at location `"C:\Users\sr7\Documents\Cordova\testApp1"`
Downloading cordova library for www...

```
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND wwwcache.sanger.ac.uk
    at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\sr7\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:168:17)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:199:16)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:272:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at net.js:923:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

It appears to still be trying to find the proxy "wwwcache.sanger.ac.uk", although I've removed the proxy info from npm (they both show null if I do "npm config ls -l").

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this, ideally within a firewall. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Being behind a proxy, I've encountered the same issue with latest version of nodejs.

To fix it, download latest version of tunnel-agent [here](https://github.com/mikeal/tunnel-agent)

and put it in the npm folder of your installed cordova-lib :

.\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent

Source of information : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8662